# Use more than one character to replace other

Tags: c#

I have a app and in this app it is possible with a function to replace some characters in a word with a other character

```
var newCharacter = "H";

if (/*something happens here and than the currentCharacter will be replaced*/)
{
    // Replace the currentCharacter in the word with a random newCharacter.
    wordString = wordString.Replace(currentCharacter, newCharacter);
}
```

now all the characters will be replaced with the code above with the "H". But i want more letters so by example the H, E, A, S

what is the best way to do this?

When i do this:

```
var newCharacter = "H" + "L" + "S";
```

it replaced the currentCharacter with H AND L AND S but i just want it to replace with H OR L OR S not all three

so if you have a word with HELLO and you want to replace the O with the newCharacter my output now is HELLHLS 
O -> HLS
but O needs to be -> H or L or S

Comment: Hi Bert, the code you posted just declares a local variable, we will need more explanations / code to be able to understand exactly what you're trying to achieve and help you. Which letters are replaced by 'H' ? Do you want to replace a letter by more than one other letter ? Based on what ? It isn't clear to me.

Comment: I read this for the 5th time now and still dont understand what you need, could you provide an example input / output

Comment: @Julien the var NewCharacters will replace the currentCharacter this could be a O or T whatever.. My app now just replace 1 currentCharacter with 1 newCharacter but i want more newCharacters so the currentCharacter will not replaced only with the H but also with other letters.

Comment: So you want to replace each occurences of a given letter in a word by other letters chosen at random ?

Comment: Yes, the newCharacter "H" is a random choosen letter this could also be a B or D but i want to have more letters to replace so the currentCharacters will not be replaced only with H but also with other random letters.

Comment: And what will happen if you replace all the **B**'s with an **H** and then you replace all the **H**'s with a **C** - now all **B**'s are also **C**'s... In other words, why don't you explain ***what*** you're trying to achieve as this is probably not the correct approach

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do using LINQ.You can add the characters you want to remove in the array **excpChar**

```
char[] excpChar= new[] { 'O','N' };
string word = "LONDON";

var result = excpChar.Select(ch => word = word.Replace(ch.ToString(), ""));
Console.WriteLine(result.Last());
```

Answer (score 0):

The Replace function replaces all the occurences at once, this is not what we want. Let's do a ReplaceFirst function, only replacing the first occurence (one could make an extension method out of this):

```
static string ReplaceFirst(string word, char find, char replacement)
{
    int location = word.IndexOf(find);
    if (location > -1)
        return word.Substring(0, location) + replacement + word.Substring(location + 1);
    else
        return word;
}
```

Then we can use a random generator to replace the target letter with different letters through successive calls of ReplaceFirst:

```
string word = "TpqsdfTsqfdTomTmeT";
char find = 'T';
char[] replacements = { 'H', 'E', 'A', 'S' };
Random random = new Random();

while (word.Contains(find))
    word = ReplaceFirst(word, find, replacements[random.Next(replacements.Length)]);
```

word now may be EpqsdfSsqfdEomHmeS or SpqsdfSsqfdHomHmeE or ...

Answer (score 0):

You can do like following :

```
string test = "abcde";
var result = ChangeFor(test, new char[] {'b', 'c'}, 'z');
// result = "azzde"
```

with ChangeFor :

```
private string ChangeFor(string input, IEnumerable<char> before, char after)
{
    string result = input;
    foreach (char c in before)
    {
        result = result.Replace(c, after);
    }
    return result;
}
```